# Using moment.js to calculate elapsed time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

```
  var currentTimeArray = [];
  function currentTime(){
    var time = moment();
    return currentTimeArray.push(time);
  }

  $('.next-fieldgroup').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    currentTime();

    var endTime = $(currentTimeArray).last();
    var startTime = currentTimeArray[0];
    var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
    var elapsedTime = duration().asMinutes();

    $('#timer-counter').text( elapsedTime );
  });
```

What it is supposed to do...

1. on click store NOW time in to ARRAY
2. on click compare arr[0] with arr.last() to get time elapsed time
3. update div with elapsed time in minutes

I expect the output to like:

"Time elapsed: 12 minutes"

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: what line is the error indicating is the cause?

Comment: @pat `var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));` this line and --fps no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery methods return objects wrapped in jQuery, so your `endTime` is a jQuery wrapped moment object. And jQuery does not have a `.diff` method so hence the error. Use `.get(0)` or `[0]` to get the actual moment object

```
var endTime = $(currentTimeArray).last().get(0);
```

Comment: In fact `get(0)` actually causes the object return undefined.

Comment: If I do this: `var endTime = $(currentTimeArray).last()[0]['_d'];` I get the actual datetime string: 'Tue Aug 19 2014 19:31:36 GMT-0400 (EDT) '

Comment: Then use `.last()[0]`, but it should do the same thing as .get(0)

Comment: I'm still getting this type error :`var duration = moment(duration( endTime.diff(startTime) ));` error undefined is not a function --- why? I'm passing in two valid times aren't I? I can console log both and they display...

Comment: `moment(duration(` is that a typo? as it should be `moment.duration(`