# Get the minutes that have elapsed through moment diff

Tags: momentjs, duration, difference

I'm trying to get the difference in minutes between two timestamps

I have a timestamp that looks like this to begin with

```
'15:44:06'
```

And when I want to find the time elapsed I create a new moment timestamp

```
var currentTimestamp = Moment(new Date()).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Which returns this

```
'15:42:09'
```

I then attempt to get the difference like so

```
var duration = Moment.duration(Moment(currentTimestamp,'HH:mm:ss').diff(Moment(userTimestamp,'HH:mm:ss')));
```

And then attempt to get it in minutes

```
var elapsedTime = duration().asMinutes();
console.log(elapsedTime);
```

But in the console when I log it I get this error

```
var elapsedTime = duration().asMinutes();
                  ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

I got most of this code from [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394406/using-moment-js-to-calculate-elapsed-time)

Comment: Can you not just then do `duration.asMinutes()`?

Comment: `duration.asMinutes()` as the error says, `duration` is an object. not a function, don't `duration()`

Comment: Ah yes a small oversight, thanks guys, I looked right over that several times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also try this with the lastest moment.js

```
var start = moment('15:44:06','HH:mm:ss');
var minutesPassed = moment().diff(start, 'minutes');
```

Comment: For UTC, use `var start = moment.utc('15:44:06','HH:mm:ss'); var minutesPassed = moment.utc().diff(start, 'minutes');`

Answer (score 16):

You can get the diff by using the moment constructor properly.

First, when you initialize your time stamp, you should use the following format:

```
var timestamp = moment('15:44:06','HH:mm:ss');
```

Second, when you want to use the diff function with the current time you should user it like so:

```
timestamp.diff(moment());
```

Then, the given number can be converted to minutes with .asMinutes() (the first )

for further information you should read the official docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: The second parameter to `moment.diff` is `unit of measure`. `timestamp.diff(moment(), 'minutes')`. [Moment - Difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Answer (score 13):

This question is getting a little bit old, this answer just bring the state up to date with a solution the question was looking for:

```
const startDate = moment();
...
elapsedDuration = moment.duration(moment().diff(startDate));
//in minutes
elapseDuration.asMinutes();
```

As per documentation about [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)
 and [display duration in minutes](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/)